# Is this kind of positioning possible - user friendly site structure and positioning - without javascript

Tags: html, css, position, margin, master-pages

So what i want to achieve is that 1000px main screen and at the right, ad space

If visitor screen width is smaller than 1160 ad screen won't be visible unless visitor scrolls right

But i want to margin things according to the main screen not total of ad place and main screen

Is this kind of positioning possible without javascript ?

Ok here the picture

[image]

Comment: Positioning has nothing to do with JavaScript. Why would JavaScript be even involved?

Comment: well i know it is not but some people may suggest jquery or javascript positioning after page load. so i included that

Comment: This is what you're talking about, right? http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/xpkaj/2/

Comment: This and related concepts are generally search-able using the phrase, "responsive design."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's posible using CSS `@media` I prefer to use percentages but here's an example:

```
#page{
    width:80%;
    margin:0% 9% 0% 10%;
}
#left{
    display:inline-block;//alternative needed for ie 8 and below
    width:80%;
}
#right{
    width:19%;
    display:inline-block;
}

@media screen only and (min-width:1160px){
    #right{
        display:none;
    }
    #left{
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

If the user's has a screen resolution width smaller than 1160px; The CSS properties of the elements will be altered.

Comment: how is this one browser support capacity ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG For ie I find setting a static `width` no `min- / max-` and `float:left;` works but it's not perfect for other browsers. I use the above because it supports the majority.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: According to [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=media), CSS3 media query support is missing from IE8 and IE7.  You can fake it with javascript (e.g., something like http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/ )

Comment: @Brian I prefer to use a sperate style sheet for IE (If I bother making one of IE). `<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" src="ie9andBelow"/><![endif]-->` more similar and specific methods can be found here:
 http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), in particular the [width feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width).

This allows you to customize the CSS according to the available width.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1160px) { … }
```